# ASP.NET Core Web API template not loading in Visual Studio Community

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

When I create project for REST API with ASP.NET Core Web API, nothing comes up. It does not load the project, nor the template, and the project is empty. I have uninstalled and reinstalled it, correctly checking all the ingredients the instructions said.

Here is a sample video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hoB-MpLZ_vs3lOBdHayHgbhehR7IQVbK/view

Comment: What's your  Visual Studio version ? You can click help -> check for updates.

Comment: It's the latest version: 17.9.1

Answer (score 0):

So what I understood afterward is that the **ASP.NET templates** are based on `dotnet` and Visual Studio Community is just an IDE that doesn't have to do anything with how a template project is bootstrapped. It can only help you write code and edit the project very easily and efficiently. My issue had to do with the version of `dotnet`. The same template projects could be bootstrapped from the CMD/Terminal, apart from Visual Studio.

When I used the **ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)** everything worked just fine, the template was generated and I was ready to edit the project. It worked fine, because I used the **.NET Framework 4.7.2 and not .NET Framework 4.8**.[image]

However, when I initiated a project with the **ASP.NET Core Web API** template, it was automatically using **.NET Framework 4.8**. For some reason, I had installed dotnetboth on the **Program Files (x86)** and **Program Files** folders on my computer. The .NET Framework 4.8 version was installed in the Program Files folder. I went into the PATH environment variable, which included both locations of Program Files (x86) and Program Files.

[image]

I **deleted Program Files (x86)** from the PATH environment variable, and everything worked just as fine afterward.